# Change field value in the cxgrid when changing another

Tags: delphi, devexpress, delphi-xe2, delphi-xe

In my cxGrid I have a Yes/No field which is by default 'NO' . Next to that field, I have another field,a LookupComboBox field that
gets its values from another table. It is empty by default however I would like that, when the value gets changed in this
particular field, my Yes/No field should change to 'YES' (Only in the row that I am currently editing) How am I to do this ? Also Not sure where to implement the code ....OnChange,Oneditvaluechanged,Onvalidate ???

Comment: Don't know cxGrid, but sounds like you are using inline editing. Therefore you would probably need the OnChange handler of the inline editor for the column containing the combo box. Within that handler you would have to restrict yourself to editing the current record of the datasource/dataset connected to the grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your grid semms to be bound on datasets one easy way would be using the fieldchange event of your selection field.
For immediate behavior you should use a TcxEditRepositoryLookupComboBoxItem with ImmediatePost instead a of a Lookupfield in your dataset (which would anyway the worse approach with at least ADO)

```
procedure TForm4.MainSelectionChange(Sender: TField);
begin

   if Main.State in [dsEdit,dsInsert] then
      if not Sender.IsNull then
        MainYesNo.Value := true;

   { maybe you are looking for that instead the code above
   if Main.State in [dsEdit,dsInsert] then
        MainYesNo.Value := not Sender.IsNull
   }
end;
```

[image: Lookup definition]
[image: Lookupusage]